# How to access an application in your browser on OpenShift

Tags: curl, browser, service, openshift-origin

I have created an application on OpenShift. This consists out of 1 pod and 1 service. It's possbile to curl to the ip of my service (on my server). So I can read it's code. For example:

```
curl 172.30.82.121:8080
```

A service is using a private IP. So it's only accessible on the server.
But I want to see the application in a browser which is not running on the server. Is this possible to do and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would install the router as described here https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/deploy_router.html

If you are just trying to test the system, you can also have your laptop send connections intended for the service VIP directly to your nodes - on OSX

```
sudo route add 172.30.0.0/16 <ip of node>
```

Or Linux

```
sudo ip route add 172.30.0.0/16 via <ip of node>
```

Or Windows

```
route add 172.30.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 <ip of node> metric 2
```

Comment: Okay thanks, this answer was right. I've created a service account, a router, and a route. Important to know when you're creating a route is that you have to use the hostname of the node where the pod of you're router is running! (I made this mistake, I chose the hostname of the node where the pods of my app were running)

Comment: One litte question: "When two routes claim the same host, the oldest route wins." So you always have to use different hosts. Do you have to create a new router on a different host to fix this issue?

Comment: Probably one router will be enough but that does not work for me. For hostname I chose the hostname of the node where te router is running. But when I'm creating a new router it's always the same name, so it always access the same app.